# CSS set space between all internal html components

Tags: html, css

I need to set a `4px` space between all html internal components (in any direction top bottom left right). I am using an external css file for this. I tried this:

```
body {
       padding: 2px;
       border: 0px;
       margin: 0px;
}
```

But this sets a space of `4px` for all body not between it's components.

Also,

```
{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 4px;
}
```

is not working either.

Can you please help. I am not allowed to change the html page.

Comment: What you means with internal components? Please show your html markup..

Comment: Also think you may want margin: 2px; instead of padding

Comment: with internal components i mean all tags inside the body of my html. All p, images, videos, lists and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
body * {
   margin: 2px;
}
```

Which will set that margin to every element inside of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like you need to set for the elements used on HTML , if you are
>   using Css preprocessor , then you can declare the values at the top
>   and later it will be used by all the elements like shown below :-

```
 $standard-padding :2px;
 $standard-border:0px;
 $standard-margin:0px;

 body,p,h1,h2,div,span{ 
   padding: $standard-padding;
   border: $standard-border;
   margin: $standard-margin;
 }
```

Comment: this would be impossible to maintain.  Every time you add a new element to your markup, you would need to update your CSS too.  Why not simply add `body * {...}` ?

Comment: yeah i would agree, body * will do the things , i was considering if we have less elements on the page then we can do my things

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try padding like this:

```
body *{
padding:4px;
}
```